# Understanding Operators

Tags: c++, operators

Our Professor has given us a practice test with the answers to help us for our upcoming test. I don't understand how the answer for this code is `135`.

I understand what a class is but I am struggling how operators work. For `v{6}` I understand that for the object `v` the `int v` equals `13`. I thought that in the int main that the first `-v` in `(-v - v).print` would be evaluated first in the operator that return `2 * v` and that it would return `26`. I then thought they would then be put in the last operator

```
V operator-(int lop, const V& rop)
{
    return rop - lop;
}
```

but I don't think that is the case. I have put this code into Visual Studio to mess around with it but I don't understand what is going on.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class V
{
    int v;

public:
    V(int a = 3, int b = 7) : v{a + b}
    {
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << v;
    }

    V operator-(const V& rop) const
    {
        return (3 * v) + (2 * rop.v) + 3;
    }

    V operator-()
    {
        return 2 * v;
    }
};

V operator-(int lop, const V& rop)
{
    return rop - lop;
}

int main() 
{
    V v{6};
    (-v - v).print();

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Operators is just a syntactic trick to replace a function named like `void subtract()` with an operator like `operator -(...)` Operators that change the lvalue usually go inside the class (like operator +=), where operators that should produce a new value are going outside the class (like operator +).

Comment: Get your line by line debugger out, and examine the behaviour. Then it will be obvious.

Comment: Hint: `2 * v` invokes the constructor with the default parameter when returned from the function. Everything else is pretty obvious. Actually @LightnessRacesinOrbit alludes to that in the previous comment.

Comment: @Bathsheba There's not much "obvious" about the code, despite it using only basic language features.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I have been warped by years of working with Boost Spirit!

Comment: @Bathsheba They have pills for that :D

Comment: Since `-v` returns an instance of the `V` class, then `-v - v` is invoking the member-function `operator-` like `(-v).operator-(v)`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Not anymore. Demand has outstripped supply.

Comment: @Bathsheba Sh!t. Hope it doesn't break your  spirit :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, this is confusing code, with re-used variable names, strange unconventional operations and such. The code is particularly hard to follow because `V` can be implicitly constructed from an integer, with 7 always added to that integer; even with a debugger, this took me a few moments to grok. Please never write code like this, not even for fun!

The result of `-v` in `main` is not an `int`. It is a `V` object implicitly constructed from the expression `2 * v` (=26), resulting in a member integer with value 33 (26+7).

It's as if you wrote:

```
V operator-()
{
    return V(2 * v);
}
```

or, due to the default argument:

```
V operator-()
{
    return V(2 * v, 7);
}
```

Then you take this new returned object and feed it to member `operator-(const V&)`; same story applies. It produces the expression `3*33 + 2*13 + 3`, which is 128; again this is used to construct a new `V` (because that's the return type!), so add 7 to get 135.

`operator-(int lop, const V& rop)` doesn't come into it because you never performed a subtraction between an `int` and a `V`.

Comment: thank you that made things a lot clearer. Ya that's the kind of problems we get on tests at my university. I definitely would not enjoy writing that kind of code and giving it to students.

Answer (score 1):

The result of `-v` is not an `int`, but a `V`.
Thus, the member-overloaded subtraction will be used.

This is the equivalent code, without the syntactic sugar of operators, but with explicit conversion of return values:

```
class V
{
public:
    V(int a = 3, int b = 7) : v{a + b}
    {
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << v;
    }

    V subtract(const V& rop) const
    {
        return V((3 * v) + (2 * rop.v) + 3);
    }

    V negate()
    {
        return V(2 * v);
    }
private:
    int v;
};


int main() 
{
    V v{6};
    (v.negate().subtract(v)).print();

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer it makes things a little bit more clear to me but how do you that -v is the operator that you call negate and not the other one you call substract?

Comment: @user296098 `-v` is "unary minus", or negation. It can't be the other operator since that has two operands.